# IWD Store Locator.... Helper Error, No support?

Tags: php, xml, helper

I've ran into a helper error after installing the IWD store locator extension and after trying their support line for 24 hours and not receiving a response from my email I thought I'd ask the world!

So, the error is...

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Storeloctor_Helper_Data' not found in /app/Mage.php on line 547
```

I know this usually means there's an error in the config.xml (notibly the obvious typo Storeloctor instead of StoreLocator - after checking the config file it shows;

```
    <helpers>
        <storelocator>
            <class>IWD_StoreLocator_Helper</class>
        </storelocator>
    </helpers>
```

Helper is defined perfectly (IWD/StoreLocator/Helper/Data.php exists), where am I going wrong?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They actually updated the extension to fix this error - the version they put me on is 1.8.7 and it works perfectly